# Samsung C404 toner chip reset using Arduino I2C

Tags: arduino, i2c

I've got a Samsung c480 laser printer with C404 series toners. They have a 3 pin chip: DATA, CLK, GND. Which makes me think of I2C, I connected it to the arduino uno A4/A5 pins but by using the [I2C scanner found on the arduino website](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/) the serial monitor gets stuck at "Scanning..." If i disconnect the chip it keeps looping on "No device found" (obv).

I've used 5k resistors as pull ups (two 10k in parallel).
What do you suggest? I would like to read the content of the chip and change the print counter.

[image: Arduino Circuit]
[image: Chip pins]
[image: Actual toner chip]

Comment: Worst case, it’s not I2C. Hook up your oscilloscope or logic analyzer and see what happens?

Comment: You don't know if it is I2C or not. Figure that out first, perhaps with the printer. As it is now, I2C would also require power to be supplied to target chip, and you don't have that, so it might not be I2C or it might be some custom I2C like protocol. Or just clock and bidirectional data. Even if it was I2C, it would not be resettable, it would be settable only, or include some password or cryptography mechanism before it is even readable.

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't have an oscilloscope, I've seen this blog where a guy does the same thing with a similar chip model http://lueftenegger.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-reset-toner-chip-of-clp-510-or.html I cannot find any datasheet to understand for sure if it is I2C or not

Comment: Speed is probably low so any cheap USB scope or logic analyzer will do the job. You can probably hack your Arduino to record it for you even.

Comment: @Winny I could use the arduino serial plotter but I don't know how to connect the arduino to the chip, which pin to use as vcc and which voltage (I used 3.3 before and I didn't kill it but I don't know if that's the right voltage)

Comment: Most probably 3.3. Turn up your lab power supply slowly and observe the current consumption. Or search for datasheets of the IC(s) used for the board. Or measure output from the printer. Trace out a schematic of the mystery board.

Comment: I don't have a lab bench ps. The board has only two components with markings are: the chip is ADP1G Q816, no datasheet online. The other one is an smd diode L43. The other components are just smd resistors and capacitors. I removed the pcb that connects to the toner chips. The chips gets 3.3 volts via the DATA pin. The data pin is connected to the data line and 3.3 via a diode (I guess)

Comment: Strange, but plausible. Did you measure 3.3 V off the printer? Please trace out a schematic from the PCB.

Comment: you can always write a simple I²C scan program that goes through all the 7bit addresses and all 10bit addresses and see which one gives you an ACK bit. Let's assume it uses I²C and you've found its address, how do you know which register to change ? I'd look for similar toner chips documentation by Samsung on the net

Comment: Yes I measured 3.3 off the printer, I've go my hands on a clone chip but I can't find any documentation of his ic either (markings are: 1949 8H WAL). I tried to use the printer's pcb and connect the arduino to it (providing sepratate 3.3v via that diode) but the script is still stuck at "scanning". I'm pretty sure it's i2c because the clone toner pcb has gnd, sda, scl labels.